# Midi-dot-net NoteOff message

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

I have a problem playing sound on `noteOff` message.

Firstable here is my `noteOn`:

```
public void NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(noteOnHandler, msg);
        return;
    }

    label_nazwy_nut.Text = String.Format("{0}", msg.Pitch);
    String nutka = label_nazwy_nut.Text;

    if (msg.Velocity == 0)
        return;

    if (nutka == "A0")
    {
        PlayEngine.Instance.PlaySound("A0");
    }
}
```

And I fully understand that, but then I have a `noteOff` looks like:

```
public void NoteOff(NoteOffMessage msg)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(noteOffHandler, msg);
        return;
    }
}
```

And I realy don't know (did not find the answer yet) and have no idea how should I use `noteOff` message. I want to play a `.wav` file same way I played it on my `noteOn` but only when I release key pressed on my keyboard midi controller.

Help and explanation is needed.

Comment: One thing to note is that many controllers don't send a Note Off message anymore when a key is released. Instead, they send a Note On with velocity 0.